# Ubuntu 18.04 mouse freezing every now and then

Tags: 18.04, mouse, logitech

I am having a major problem, mouse freezes every now and then for few seconds until some event occurs, soon some event occurs mouse resumes then again after some time it freezes, my mouse is logitech wireless, laptop Dell.

Steps I tried,

1. Dist Upgrade.